# mount rootfs on loopback

Tags: linux, rootfs

I have a rootfs boot image that I want to test by mounting on my local file system. How can I do this ?

EDIT: The file was a rootfs.img but it turned out I did not have the correct filesystem support in my custom kernel. pjz's answer works once the fs support is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need more info - what kind of image is it?

is it a file that's a filesystem?  if so you mount it like:

```
  mount -o loop rootfs.img /mnt/rootfs
```

if it's a subdir of your filesystem that you'r exporting via nfs, you can simulat ethe environment you've created by chrooting to it:

```
  chroot /path/to/nfs/rootdir/
```